# How can I open a file and move the cursor to the end of the first line?

Tags: git, vim

How can I open a file and (via a command line argument to `vim`) move the cursor to the end of the first line, and enter append mode? Specifically, I'm using a git `prepare-commit-message` hook to prepend a tag to a commit message, so my prepared commit message will look like this:

```
[SOMETAG] 
#         ^--- I want to position the cursor here, and enter insert mode
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# ...
```

Essentially, the string `"[SOMETAG] "` with a trailing space is being inserted into the commit message, and I want Vim to behave exactly like I'd opened the file and hit `A` to move to begin appending to the first line in the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-c` to give a command after the file is read:

```
vim foo -c 'star!'
```

I don’t think you can set a specific editor to be used only for `git-commit`, nor can a hook influence your choice of editor.

Comment: The idea was to set `GIT_EDITOR`. Thanks; I guess the real question I was asking was, "how can I move the cursor and enter insert mode via Ex"

Comment: Or, `vim +1 +star! foo`.  It's reasonable to explicitly navigate to the first line (if one has configured Vim to restore last cursor position in a file).  Also, it's not necessary to escape bang sign here.